# Styling Select element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

OK, so here's the situation:

- I've got a styled `<select>` element
- On the right part of its (transparent) background, I want to show some up arrow (preferably a Bootstrap Glyphicon)

The issue:

- The icon appears fine (in the fiddle it shows up like a square icon, for some reason, but it doesn't matter)
- However when clicking on the icon, the select is not triggered - which is not correct.

Any ideas?

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="styled-select">
    <select>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
select {
    border:0; 
    border-radius: 0;
    background:transparent; 
    outline:none; 
    box-shadow:none; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:none; 
    text-align:right;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    padding-top: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#styled-select:hover {
    color: #666;
}

#styled-select:after {
    content:"\e113";
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
    line-height:1;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

---

**Demo/Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tnzbL1hp/

Comment: Why did you tagged __bootstrap__?

Comment: @Satpal Because the website *is* Bootstrap-3.2.0-based. (If you notice, in the jsFiddle, it's the only "external resource" added). -- EDIT: Ah, ok, I missed it - it should have been `twitter-bootstrap`!

Comment: @Satpal if you don't agree why no use the 'edit' function and start a discussion there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another solution I just came up with:

```
    #styled-select:after {
        content:"\e113";
        font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
        line-height:1;
        display:inline-block;

        pointer-events:none;

        width: 23px;
        height: 23px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 4px;

    }
```

And add some `padding-right` to the `<select>` element...

Answer (score 2):

Added this:

```
select {
    margin-right:-30px;
    padding-right:25px;
}
```

and

```
#styled-select:after {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnzbL1hp/1/

Comment: You might also want to remove the whitespace between inline level elements: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/tnzbL1hp/4/

Comment: thtats not showing an icon, i tried it, even in jsfiddle output it is showing a block instead an icon